# Locking an individual WhatsApp message

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

On my SMS messaging app (Go SMS Pro)I can lock individual messages within a thread/conversation so that if I want to delete the majority of my messages from a sender I can still save important ones and prevent them from being deleted. With WhatsApp it seems I can only delete an entire message thread and there is no way of saving individual messages within a thread. Is this correct or have I missed something? 
Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Though there is no official way, there's still a work around.

1. Star the messages you want to keep.
2. Then go to chat>Options>Clear chat
3. It will prompt you with three options.
4. Go with "Clear except Starred"

   And you're good to go.

Comment: Yes. That's a useful workaround +1

Answer (score 1):

## This is correct

There is **no way** currently to *lock* individual messages to prevent them from being deleted according to [WhatsApp Support](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/).

You can, however, select several messages to be exported:

> Click on Options > Settings > Chat History > Send chat history.

You will then be able to send your chat history via email or through some other application.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand there is no option to lock individual messages in WhatsApp. But I do it in a different way.

You can create a Whatsapp group by adding anybody, then remove that person. Now, the group includes one member only; that is you.

Any important messages you can forward to this GROUP so that they will remain there as long as you want. However, it can not be locked with a password. But you can clear other group chats if you want.